# What happens if someone bounces a cheque in US?

Tags: criminal-law, finance, banking

From my knowledge, if A gives cheque to B and cheque bounces, then a warrant is issued against A.

1. Is the warrant issued anytime cheque bounces by default ?
2. Or B has to press charges against A for cheque to bounce ?

Answer (score 3):

A warrant is never automatically issued. A warrant (I assume you mean arrest warrant) can be issued under court orders, if there is probable cause to believe that a crime has been committed. If a court orders A to pay money to B and A does not, A can be arrested. A court will not *sua sponte* make such an order without some petition by a harmed party. So B could sue A for the amount owed, and the burden is on B.

There are criminal laws that pertain to check bouncing, for example in Washington under [RCW 9a.56.060](http://apps.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=9A.56.060) it is a crime, but not every check-bouncing is a crime. You have to have "intent to defraud", "knowing at the time..that he or she has not sufficient funds". If convicted you will be fined, and may be imprisoned. Even in the case of a fraudulent intent, there is no automatic warrant (the police do not know what has come to pass). B does not "press charges", but they can complain to the police who may investigate and find that there is evidence of fraudulent intent (which can lead to an arrest warrant). They may also conclude that the evidence of fraud is insufficient.

Comment: So if B does not press charges, now warrant is issued right?

Comment: The government gets the warrant, so it is up to them. If they don't know about the matter, they won't ask for a warrant. If they know but feel that B's cooperation is necessary, they probably won't ask for a warrant. The bank might be involved, though. It really depends on whether the government cares about prosecuting the case, which covers things like "knows that", "has enough evidence" and "has more pressing concerns".